# input.equals("string here") not working

Tags: java, string, timezone

I am new to Java. I'm trying to make a program where the user inputs a country and it returns the current time in that country. I have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a country: ");
    String userCountryInput = userInput.nextLine();

    if (userInput.equals("Philippines")) {
        Date date1 = new Date();
        System.out.println(date1);
    }

    if (userInput.equals("Russia")) {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC + 05:30"));

        Date date2 = new Date();
        System.out.println(date2);
    }
}
```

When I enter "Russia" or "Philippines" it does not output anything. Any idea why?

Comment: asking for books will lead to a discussion, which isn't the aim on this site. In my opinion if Java is the first language, you're learning, you should choose a book in your mothertongue. The most books will cover the basic needs and after you got started, you will learn the most as you need it by reading in forums, apis or solving problems.

Answer (score 3):

`userCountryInput` is the input variable. `userInput` is the Scanner variable used to get the input

```
if ("Philippines".equals(userCountryInput)) {
```

Comment: if (userInput == "Philippines") gives me an error. it says "incomparable types: scanner and string"

Comment: that makes no sense - just compare the String returned from `nextLine` with the literal value

Comment: Okay sorry, I got it. Rookie statement I made right there. Thank you, Reimeus

Comment: @DylanVillaruel and why would you use `==` to compare strings when you seem to already know that [you should use `euqlas`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)?

Comment: @Pshemo I just knew, like a few minutes ago. I dont have any keen knowledge on the functions yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are using equals on `userInput` wich is the scanner and not the string. It will work on the string `userCountryInput` :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a country: ");
    String userCountryInput = userInput.nextLine();

    if (userCountryInput .equals("Philippines")){

        Date date1 = new Date();
        System.out.println(date1);
    }

    if (userCountryInput .equals("Russia")){
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC + 05:30"));

        Date date2 = new Date();
        System.out.println(date2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you man! I got it now

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, you are mixing up the `userInput` with `userCountryInput`.

You should use better names for your variables so you don't mix them up again in the future. For example, it might be worth to rename `userCountryInput` to `userCountry`.